# Exoplayer 2: Play video in reverse

Tags: android, video, exoplayer2.x

My android app plays videos in Exoplayer 2, and now I'd like to play a video backwards.
I searched around a lot and found only the idea to convert it to a gif and [this from WeiChungChang](https://github.com/WeiChungChang/ExoPlayer).
Is there any more straight-forward solution? Another player or a library that implements this for me is probably too much to ask, but converting it to a reverse gif gave me a lot of memory problems and I don't know what to do with the WeiChungChang idea. Playing only mp4 in reverse would be enough tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Videos are frequently encoded such that the encoding for a given frame is dependent on one or more frames before it, and also sometimes dependent on one or more frames after it also.

In other words to create the frame correctly you may need to refer to one or more previous and one or more subsequent frames.

This allows a video encoder reduce file or transmission size by encoding fully the information for every reference frame, sometimes called I frames, but for the frames before and/or after the reference frames only storing the delta to the reference frames.

Playing a video backwards is not a common player function and the player would typically have to decode the video as usual (i.e. forwards) to get the frames and then play them in the reverse order.

You could extend ExoPlayer to do this yourself but it may be easier to manipulate the video on the server side if possible first - there exist tools which will reverse a video and then your players will be able to play it as normal, for example https://www.videoreverser.com, https://www.kapwing.com/tools/reverse-video etc

If you need to reverse it on the device for your use case, then you could use ffmpeg on the device to achieve this - see an example ffmpeg command to do this here:

- https://video.stackexchange.com/a/17739

If you are using ffmpeg it is generally easiest to use via a wrapper on Android such as this one, which will also allow you test the command before you add it to your app:

- https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java

Note that video manipulation is time and processor hungry so this may be slow and consume more battery than you want on your mobile device if the video is long.